# Floor cleaning in camera raw and photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

In the picture up we notice dirt in the floor. How can we remove this using photoshop and camera raw in a way that gives it a kind of gloss?

Comment: What have you tried? Your best bets are going to be either airbrush skill or finding a better floor to put in place and match up the lighting.

Comment: Like @ryan said, find a better floor image

Comment: If any of the answers below is satisfactory, please tick the "accepted answer" tickmark next to it. Good for you, me, us.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have 4 options, and as for 90% of things done in Photoshop, it's all a matter of skills and using the tools you have. No automatic "floor cleaner" in Photoshop unfortunately. At least one option doesn't require any Photoshop skill at all!

## 1. Use a broom before taking pictures of shinny surfaces

Personally, I really like the Oskar from Vileda. It's awesome for corners and very lightweight.

It's way faster and easier to prepare the surface in real than fix in Photoshop (no matter what people say or think.) And it's also way cheaper! The more you need to modify a picture's pixels, the more skills you'll need to make it look realistic.

[image: Broom]

## 2. Clone Stamp Tool

As suggested in the comments you got, get to work and start removing the dust manually. Now frankly, there's so much dust that I think it would look horrible no matter how good you are with the stamp tool.

Plus you'll probably need to artificially reapply some glossy effect because the stamp tool will remove it.

**Info on clone stamp tool:**

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/retouching-repairing-images.html

## 3. Diminish the dust (not perfect)

Use the blending modes and apply some overlay blend mode in color to saturate the dust with another color. This is not perfect though but it's fast and has a ok result for small pictures.

If you want some shine you'll need to add it back with another layer. That might actually help hiding the imperfection caused by the dust.

[image: Floor fix removing dust in Photoshop]

## 4. Just stick a new floor

As suggested in the comments you got, find a similar floor and add it with the right perspective and shadow in Photoshop. You'll need to use the wall's angle to align the planks of the floor.

You'll probably need to apply some shadows in the corners to make it more realistic. I didn't do it in my example.

[image: New floor installed in Photoshop]

You'll need to use [layer mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html) for all this.

Comment: You're entirely too nice but upvoted for the broom.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution:

First of all you shloud make the floor

Second we are not dealing in the photo with "dirt" but we are dealing with variant colors that give the effect of the dirt. we are not going polishing the floor as @go-me said, but it should be polished before taking your shoot. Part of getting a best shoot is to prepare your scene before shooting -if it possible.

Also we are not replacing floor with other one, this process will be an extreme makeover I don't recommend because it may lead to be asked to model the scene in any 3D software to get a better scale, proportions and perspective for the floor spreads (why not !!). - I am not recommending that.

It is all about colors correction.

I decreased the effect of white in the floor for the sake of the wood color.

I did the job with some `adjust > Shadow highlights` to reduce the effect of the highlights color "white" and decrease the effect of the shadow to make a big contrast between what is highlighted "dirt or the white color" and the rest of the wooden floor, and in the same dialogue box I raised the color correction to get a better result.

After that I raised the "Vibrance" `Adjust > Vibrance` to remove the white blotch in the floor as I an eliminating a fog in a photo.

Till that you can get a good result but here you are the nice tip for more better result:

Some very little reflections on the floor will gives the desired impression of the gloss, even if some blotches remain on the floor. (to be more realistic.)

here is my result.

[image]